# Finding slow query log in Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL on Windows 8.1. I got to find MySQL `slow.log` to do performance tuning on my queries. In case of Ubuntu it can be found from `/var`
`log/mysqlslow.log`.

From where can I find it in Windows 8.1?

Answer (score 0):

In a default installation of MySql, all log files and databases a located under:

If MySql is version 5.5

C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data

Or

%programdata%\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data

But you can change the path after or during installation.

Comment: after getting into data what i have to click ?

Comment: There is a file that ends with "-slow.log"
On my pc, the file name is "mypcname-sloq.log"

Comment: Remember to activate slow query log in my.ini file.
In my.ini add or edit line under

[mysqld]

slow_query_log=1

Answer (score 0):

Open my.cnf or my.ini file, and look for variable mentioned below.

```
log-slow-queries = [path to the log file]
```

This is the place where it stores slow query log.

Thanks

Amit